# Ошибка кодировки при работе с pip

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При попытке установить pip появляется ошибка, связанная с кодировкой. Как это можно исправить?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: в Anaconda уже есть pip

Comment: приводите сообщение об ошибке в виде текста, а не картинки (чтобы другие люди с похожей проблемой могли бы найти этот вопрос в будущем).

Comment: что происходит, если запустить `python -mpip install -U pip`?

Comment: @jfs выдает аналогичную ошибку

Comment: @Александр: приведите ошибку целиком в вопросе (как текст -- поместите в `<code>` блок, чтобы сохранить форматирование).

Comment: @jfs исправил, так лучше?

Comment: "Приведите ошибку целиком" (можно просто всё скопировать из консоли, начиная с самой команды: `python -mpip install -U pip`). Если не знаете как скопировать текст из консоли или как его в вопрос добавить сохраняя форматирование, то спрашивайте (последнее на [meta] лучше спросить).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал найти в интернете темы схожие с ошибкой в вашей консоли. Автор утверждает что необходимо изменить название компьютера на латинский лад, с кириллицы например Admin-ПК — Admin-PC). Источник тут: python.su/forum/topic/27663 так же развернутое обсуждение имеется тут github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2501 - одному из авторов так же помогло переименование название компьютера (автор Andrej730 ).